# Flat file data to multiple send ports biztalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have requirement where I need to send Flat file data to multiple customers.

One way is to create Send port for each of the customer and put a filter on the port to send the data specific to the Customer ID.

Now problem that I see is that customer will increase in coming days for sure so creating a new port for each customer is not a big deal but still I looking for some dynamic approach.

Can this be done with some kind of dynamic configuration for a single port?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Dynamic Send Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578717%28v=bts.20%29.aspx). This will give you the possibility to either use information in the message to configure the destination of the port *run time*. Another way is to have a database where you use some sort of customer id in the message to look up the destination and use that to configure the send port run time.